# using AJAX to make loader? status is not returned from DB

Tags: php, javascript

```
function main()
{
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        ab=new XMLHttpRequest;  
    }   
    else
    {
        ab=new ActiveXObject("Microsft.XMLHttp");

    }

    ab.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(ab.readyState==4 && ab.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML=ab.responseText;  
    }   

    }
    ab.open("GET","querygoogle.php");
    ab.send();

}
function test(id)
{
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest; 
    }   
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsft.XMLHttp");

    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;  
        //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);  
    }   

    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php",0);
    xmlhttp.send();

}




function interval()
{       
    main(); 

    setInterval('test(<? echo $_SESSION['id'];?>)','5000');

    //test();


}
```

In main function i call .php which inserts data in db and has execution time of 4 min...in test.php i am just using SELECT query to get status of the inserted data.
main.php runs fine but when i run test.php with an interval of 5 secs..i don't get any result and it just keeps on processing.

Answer (score 0):

I am really not sure what you are talking about, but [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works) makes your life easier:

```
function main() {
    $.post("querygoogle.php", function(result) {
        $(#progress).html(result);
    });
}

function test(id) {
    $.post("test.php?id=" + id, function(result) {
        $(#testdiv).html(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: sorry.. can't make sense out of that